# moment returns Invalid Date on Internet Explorer and Safari

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to convert a date that I am getting from a calendar to specific format.
So I am getting the value of the calendar using the specific selector date picker:

```
var ChkinDate = $('#myCheckinDate').data('datepicker').getDate();
// the value I am getting is: ChkinDate=Mon Apr 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time);
```

Now I am trying to convert this date to a specific format

```
var CheckinDate = moment(new Date(TimezoneDate(ChkinDate))).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
function TimezoneDate(objDate) {
  if (IsEmpty(objDate)) {
    return moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00');
  }
  else {
    return moment(objDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00');
  }
}
```

This is working perfectly on Windows machines using Chrome Browser and Mozilla Firefox, but when I am using Internet Explorer I am getting "Invalid Date" in the variable `CheckinDate`. The issue also occur on Mac machines, but now I am getting "Invalid Date" on Safari but it is working well on Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting a JavaScript Date you can use the following code:

```
function TimezoneDate(objDate) {
  if (IsEmpty(objDate)) {
    return moment();
  }
  else {
    return moment(objDate);
  }
}

var ChkinDate = $('#myCheckinDate').data('datepicker').getDate();
var CheckinDate = TimezoneDate(ChkinDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Use [`moment(Date)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/) to get a moment object from your JavaScript date and then you can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to get the moment in the format you prefer (e.g. `format('MM/DD/YYYY')` or `format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`).

In my sample `TimezoneDate` function returns a moment object, so you can call [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) (specifying the format you need) on it.

---

Here a live working sample (mocking `IsEmpty` and `ChkinDate`):

```js
// Mocking IsEmpty function
function IsEmpty(obj){
  if(obj) return false;
  return true;
}
function TimezoneDate(objDate) {
  if (IsEmpty(objDate)) {
    return moment();
  }
  else {
    return moment(objDate);
  }
}

//var ChkinDate = $('#myCheckinDate').data('datepicker').getDate();
// Mocking datepicker date
var ChkinDate = new Date(2017, 5, 10);
var CheckinDate = TimezoneDate(ChkinDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
console.log(CheckinDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello I am geting "Object doesn't support property or method 'format'"

Comment: @focus edited my answer adding a working snippet. Are you sure you are using the same code?